# Show the linear operators is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm facing some troubles with exercises about bounded operators. Let me first give the problem and what I have so far.

Let $T: L^{2}(0,1) \rightarrow L^{2}(0,1)$ be defined by
\begin{equation}Tf(x) = \int^{1}_{0} e^{x-t}f(t)dt,\space \space x \in [0,1]
\end{equation}
Now I have to prove that a) $T$ is bounded, b) dim ran $T =1$ and that c) $T$ is compact. Now I know that c) follows from a) and b) because of Bolzano-Weierstrass.
To show that $T$ is bounded I have the following

\begin{equation}
\|T\| = sup _{\|f\|_{2} = 1}\|Tf\| \leq sup_{\|f\|_{2}=1}\sqrt{\int^{1}_{0} e^{2(x-t)}f(t)^{2}dt} \leq e*sup_{\|f\|_{2}=1}\|f\|_{2}=e
\end{equation} 
So $\|T\| \leq e$ and hence bounded. Im not sure if I made wrong assumptions in my computation. I also had a hint that said not to compute $\|T\|$, is there another way?
Then I'm left to show that dim ran $T =1$, intuitively I see that we go from $\mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ so the dimension of the range is 1. Is there a conclusive proof to show this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: $Tf(x)$ is a multiple of $e^x$, which spans a 1 dimensional subspace of $L^2(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from Cauchy Schwarz:
$|T(f)(x)|=\leq \int_0^1{e^{(x-t)}}^2dt\int_0^1f(t)^2dt\leq M\|f(t)\|_2$

You have $(x-t)^2\leq (2-t)^2, x\in [0,1]$, let $M=\int_0^1e^{{(2-t)^2}}dt$. We have $|T(f(x))|\leq M\int_0^1f^2(t)dt=M\|f\|_2$. This implies that $\|T(f)\|_2=\int_0^1|T(f)(t)|^2dt\leq\int_0^1M^2\|f\|_2dt\leq M^2\|f\|_2$.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the inner product,
$$
              Tf = \langle  f, e^{-t}\rangle e^{x}
$$
This is easily shown to be continuous because $e^{-x}$ and $e^{x}$ are in $L^2[0,1]$. Obviously $T$ is a rank one operator, which makes it compact as well.